# Unable to retrieve an array of Items in my realm database

Tags: react-native, realm

I'm trying to retrieve an array from a table called `Item` from my local database which has  about 42 records which I created in order to query and test later. However I want to see what the data looks like when I request it on a button press function.
Bellow is my component:

```
const TestIndex = () => {
  const config = {
    schema: [ItemSchema],
  };

  const realm = new Realm(config);

  const onSaveItem = async () => {
    const items = await realm.objects("Item");

    return console.log(items);
  };


  return <Button buttonText="Save" buttonPress={onSaveItem} />;
}
```

and my schema is as follows:

```
export const ItemSchema = {
  name: "Item",
  properties: {
    _id: "objectId",
    itemCode: "string",
    itemDescription: "string",
    itemPrice: "string",
    partition: "string",
  },
  primaryKey: "_id",
};
```

And when I run the function I was expecting an array of objects containing my data but I got this when I `console.log(items)`:

```
Proxy {isRealmCtor: true}
[[Handler]]: Object
get: ƒ ()
arguments: null
caller: null
length: 0
name: ""
prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
__proto__: ƒ ()
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[0]
getOwnPropertyDescriptor: ƒ ()
getPrototypeOf: ƒ ()
has: ƒ ()
ownKeys: ƒ ()
set: ƒ ()
setPrototypeOf: ƒ ()
__proto__: Object
[[Target]]: Results
[[IsRevoked]]: false
```

here's an image to have a better understanding of the results:
[image: Error Image]

Comment: There are a couple of issues with the code but can you move the `console.log(items);` before the return statement and then remove the return statement?

Comment: found a solution had to ```map``` items and now I'm getting all the objects

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best option but it works...

You can try to do something similar to this:

```
const onSaveItem = async () => {

   const resp = await realm.objects("Item");

   const items = Array.from(resp);

   return items;
};
```